# Publishing an app into playstore - error uploading .apk

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-auto

I am uploading an .apk file to publish my app in play store but I am facing this problem can any one help me solve this problem.

Upload failed

> You must accept the Android Auto Addendum before uploading an Android
>   Auto-enabled APK. You can do this from the Pricing and Distribution
>   page

Screenshot of error

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASo0X.png)

Comment: screenshot is already self explained..

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to `Price and Distribution` page of you application
2. Find `Android Auto`
3. Accept `Term of Use` on the right.

Comment: Hi llya, how we can accept that for all apps at once for past and future apps in play store

Answer (score 1):

You must accept the Android Auto Addendum before uploading an Android Auto-enabled APK or Android App Bundle. You can do this from the Pricing and Distribution page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check **content guidelines** and **US export laws** see screenshot below
[image: check these options]